# How do i write a file to my classpath(resource folder) in spring boot?

Tags: spring-boot

I'm trying to write an serialized object file to my class path which will be later used for read purpose. I have written the below code,

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("src/main/resources/ListOfIotcontentObjects");
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
oos.writeObject(fileList);
```

So while building the project with `mvn clean package` its creating the executable .jar without any exception, but when i tried to run the .jar it's saying `(The system cannot find the path specified)`

I don't understand what's going wrong here and how i can make it work ? thanks in advance.

**Edit 1**: To write/create the file in resource folder i have tried the below code which is throwing `NullPointerException`.

```
        ArrayList<DevicesPOJO> employees = new ArrayList<>();    
        employees.add(new DevicesPOJO(100, 1001, "Shaik", "Nasir", 12233456));
        employees.add(new DevicesPOJO(101, 1002, "Shaik", "Nasir", 12233654));
        employees.add(new DevicesPOJO(102, 1003, "Shaik", "Nasir", 12233465));


        ClassLoader classLoader = TestApplication.class.getClass().getClassLoader(); 
        File file = new File(classLoader.getResource("./ListOfIotcontentObjects").getFile());
        System.out.println(file.getPath());
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
        oos.writeObject(employees);
        System.out.println("Success...");
```

Can anyone help me with this exception ?

Comment: Try to use t                                                                                                          `ClassLoader classLoader = this.getClass().getClassLoader();
        File file = new File(classLoader.getResource("./ListOfIotcontentObjects").getFile());
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);`

Comment: thanks for the response, i have tried the code now i'm getting the NullPointerException.

Comment: Hi Ehab Qadah, i have tried the above code for which its is giving me the null pointer.